# Java - no puedo leer socket UDP desde puerto/ip

Tags: java

Necesito leer desde una ip/puerto, mediante UDP y no lo consigo. Desde un utilitario externo, veo que el lector (RFID) lee correctamente desde dicho puerto/ip mediante UDP. Ahora bien, yo quiero leerlo desde java y no puedo (aclaro que es la primera vez que voy a leer desde un puerto/ip mediante java). Mi codigo es el siguiente, espero me puedan guiar:

```
package test_rfid_udp;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Test_RFID_UDP {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      int port = 2000;

      // Create a socket to listen on the port.
      DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket();

      // Create a buffer to read datagrams into. If a
      // packet is larger than this buffer, the
      // excess will simply be discarded!
      byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

      // Create a packet to receive data into the buffer
      InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.77");
      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, address, 2000);

      // Now loop forever, waiting to receive packets and printing them.
      while (true) {
        // Wait to receive a datagram
        dsocket.receive(packet);

        // Convert the contents to a string, and display them
        String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
        System.out.println(packet.getAddress().getHostName() + ": "
        + msg);

        // Reset the length of the packet before reusing it.
        packet.setLength(buffer.length);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Tambien les adjunto una imagen de las lecturas realizadas con el utilitario.
Espero puedan ayudarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: Tienes un código que espera mensajes a través de UDP, pero me extraña que antes de "escuchar" no envíes nada. ¿El emisor no requiere nada para iniciar el envío de datos?

Comment: @PabloLozano realmente no lo sé. Me pasaron un lector y la ip/puerto. Mediante el utilitario lo leo...pero luego, desde mi codigo no leo nada.

Comment: Un detalle: en la imagen aparece "localhost port: 2000", y remote port 5001. Me parece que estás escuchando el puerto 2000 cuando deberías escuchar el 5001

Comment: @PabloLozano ya lo probé y no. El puerto 5001 es el puerto para la configuracion del lector, por lo que me indicaron. De todas maneras, con el utilitario intenté leer del puerto 5001 y no recibo nada....solo recibo con la ip 192.168.0.77:2000

Comment: Alguna ayuda mas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He estado mirando la documentación del API de Java para UDP y la verdad es que no es muy intuitiva:

> ```
> DatagramPacket(byte[] buf, int offset, int length, InetAddress address, int port)
> ```
>
> Constructs a datagram packet for **sending** packets of length length
>   with offset `offset` to the specified port number on the specified host.

Tú lo que quieres es recibir, por tanto creo que no hay que especificar el puerto o la IP ahí:

> `DatagramPacket(byte[] buf, int length)` 
>   Constructs a DatagramPacket for **receiving** packets of length `length`.

Y para escuchar el puerto, sería algo como

```
DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket();
dsocket.connect(address,port);
```

No he podido probar este código, pero creo que de algún modo tienes que hacerle saber al emisor que estás esperando paquetes suyos, y eso es (creo) lo que hace el método `connect`

Comment: sigo teniendo el mismo inconveniente. Si lo paro con el debuger, se queda clavado en el receive...de ahi no mueve nunca. No sé que es lo que falta o lo que está mal. No dá ninguna exception ni nada

Comment: Bueno, ya encontré el problema (o los problemas). Tú posteo @PabloLozano fue de mucha ayuda, me faltaba el connect (tambien funciona con bind), pero el principal inconveniente fue Windows!...el mismo código, pero con el connect y sobre linux funciona correctamente, mientras que en windows, por mas que le agregue el connect, no funciona. Gracias